# Android java plugin call to method returns zero

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I'm using android java plugin to call my java function in unity like this:

```
static IntPtr cls_Activity;
static IntPtr fid_Activity;
static IntPtr obj_Activity;
static IntPtr kdataActivityClass;
static IntPtr startAdsMethod;

    void Start () {
        cls_Activity = AndroidJNI.FindClass("com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer");
        fid_Activity = AndroidJNI.GetStaticFieldID(cls_Activity, "currentActivity", "Landroid/app/Activity;");
        obj_Activity = AndroidJNI.GetStaticObjectField(cls_Activity, fid_Activity);
        kdataActivityClass = AndroidJNI.FindClass("com/kdata/unitytest/UnityUrlPlugin");
        startAdsMethod = AndroidJNI.GetMethodID(PakdataActivityClass, "getURL","()V");
        Debug.Log("obj_Activity"+obj_Activity);     
        Debug.Log("kdataActivityClass"+kdataActivityClass);     
        Debug.Log("Method"+startAdsMethod);     
            if (AndroidJNI.IsInstanceOf(obj_Activity, kdataActivityClass) != false)
            {                 
               jvalue[] myArray = new jvalue[1];
               AndroidJNI.CallStaticStringMethod(obj_Activity, startAdsMethod, myArray);
            }
```

The problem is that I am getting access to the class but method from the class is returns null

`Debug.Log("obj_Activity"+obj_Activity);` =>retuns value
`Debug.Log("kdataActivityClass"+kdataActivityClass);` =>returns =>value
`Debug.Log("Method"+startAdsMethod);` =>retunns null <=== here is the problem this method

Should return a hardcoded string but its not working in unity.

Help is highly appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check getURL method jni signature with javap (did you put the same to your third parameter ?) :

```
cd <pathToUnityUrlPluginClass>

javap -p -s <UnityUrlPlugin>
```

Comment: **this function takes no parameret and it returns a simple string** 
**even if I pass a " "=> null its still the same and i didnt get** **what u said above about javap can u plz elaborate i have never** **used this kind of thing before so its hard to understand--would be **
**grat if u elaborate plz** 
thanks **

Comment: **C:\>cd "C:\Documents and Settings\Shoaib Ahmed Khan\work** **asses\com\pakdata\unitytest\javap" -p -s UnityUrlPlugin**
it says sysytem cannot find the path specified and my calss file insside unitytest folder

Comment: Thanks alot brother it was a signature issue :)

Comment: sergey can u plz tell how can i take string value in my array 
value[] myArray = new jvalue[2];
        myArray[0]. i = 2;
        myArray[1]. ? = "khan";
        gui.text=   AndroidJNI.CallStaticStringMethod(obj_Activity, startAdsMethod, myArray);